# Username Array that will be save in the localStorage

Tags: javascript

I want to make an array that will have a few usernames in it and the array will be in the localstorage but if you have already have the username include the array so its wont add it again.
Tried very much !!

JavaScript

```js
var username;

function save() {
  username = ["ssfs", "s", "v"];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    if (username.indexOf(user.value) >= 0) {
      break;
    } else {
      username.push(user.value);
      localStorage.setItem('username', username)
    }
  i++


}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
input {} button {
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='main' class="main">
    <header></header>

    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Name" />
    <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
    <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password Confirm" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="save()">Save</button>
    <button>Home Page</button>

    <footer></footer>
    <div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my approach:

```
var username;
    username = ["ssfs","s","v"];
function save(user){
    var isAlreadyInserted = false;
    //loop through your username array to check
        for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
            if (username[i] === currentUserName) {
                isAlreadyInserted = true;
            }
        }

        //if the username is not in the array, insert it
        if (!isAlreadyInserted) {
            username.push(user.value);
        }
            localStorage.setItem('username', username)
}
```

In my opinion you need to pass the current user to save to the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the else part of your code, use the following snippet:

```
var flag=0;

for each (var item in username) 
{
  if(user.value == item)
  {
        flag=1;
  }
}
if(!flag)
{
     username.push(user.value);
     localStorage.setItem('username', username);
}
```